# Read access violation in tree structure

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I'm working on this assignment and I can't seem to stop this read access violation error. I am new to C++ and I think part of my issue is using pointers when they aren't necessary (I think), but I've also looked at this code and traced through it so many times with the debugger that I think I'm missing something obvious.

The assignment is to implement a Huffman encoder. To do this I have to create a HuffmanTree class and a HuffmanProcedure class, and I am provided with a (mostly) complete Heap class (minheap).

The HuffmanProcedure class has to use the Heap class to store and create HuffmanTrees until I have a Huffman code for every single lowercase letter.

When running the code, I get a read access violation error in the helper I wrote for my Tree destructor, `treeRemovalHelper`.

The specific error I get (using Visual Studio 2019 targeting C++11):
`Exception thrown: read access violation. root was 0xDDDDDDDD`

Here's where the error is occurring:

```
// Destructor
HuffmanTree::~HuffmanTree() {
  if (rootPtr != nullptr) {
    rootPtr = treeRemovalHelper(rootPtr);
  } else {
    delete rootPtr;
  }
}
```

```
// Helper
HuffmanTree::Node* HuffmanTree::treeRemovalHelper(Node* root)
{
  if (root == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  else {
      treeRemovalHelper(root->rightChild); // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
      treeRemovalHelper(root->leftChild);
      delete root;
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

Can you help point me in the right direction here?

I am happy to provide my full code, just in case it helps. I want to note that all of the code is mine, with the exception of some of the methods in the Heap class (which the instructor provided, and I have noted in the code).

Here are the three constructors for the HuffmanTree class:

```
HuffmanTree::HuffmanTree() : rootPtr(nullptr)  {}

HuffmanTree::HuffmanTree(const char letter, const int weight) {
  rootPtr = new Node{
    letter,
    weight,
    nullptr,
    nullptr
  };
}

HuffmanTree::HuffmanTree(HuffmanTree* smallestTree, HuffmanTree* secondSmallestTree)
{

  int mergedWeight = smallestTree->rootPtr->weight + secondSmallestTree->rootPtr->weight;

  char tempChar;

  if (smallestTree->rootPtr->letter < secondSmallestTree->rootPtr->letter) {
    tempChar = smallestTree->rootPtr->letter;
  } else {
    tempChar = secondSmallestTree->rootPtr->letter;
  }

  rootPtr = new Node{
    tempChar,
    mergedWeight,
    smallestTree->rootPtr,
    secondSmallestTree->rootPtr
  };
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing an assignment in the middle of a destructor? You should be cleaning house. That return value seems pointless, assigning to `nullptr` is just wasted effort. You can also just call `delete` on `nullptr`, it's a no-op.

Comment: Why is removing the children the job of the tree? `delete root` should take care of it as `root` "owns" those pointers.

Comment: It's also worth considering if `root` needs to be a pointer at all. Why not just have a `root` element in your tree?

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre]. In particular, the constructor for your class as it is possible that you are not initializing all of the members in the constructor.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm just updated

Comment: In HuffmanTree::Node* HuffmanTree::treeRemovalHelper(Node* root), you always return **nullptr**, can that method be **void** instead?

Comment: `root` is almost certainly a wild pointer.  Run your code through `valgrind` or build with address sanitizer enabled (they'll help identify where `root` is invalidated).

Comment: @ziemowit141 `treeRemovalHelper` can be void for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem:
After you delete the root, remember to set it to nullptr.

```
// Helper
HuffmanTree::Node* HuffmanTree::treeRemovalHelper(Node* root)
{
  if (root == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  else {
      treeRemovalHelper(root->rightChild); // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
      treeRemovalHelper(root->leftChild);
      delete root;
      root = nullptr; -->> FIX
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```